# all pairs 1 algorithm java

Tags: arrays, algorithm, hashmap, cosine-similarity

I stuck in one problem here. I´m trying to implement All-Pairs algorithm. I have 5 arrays with double values and for each position of the arrays (I call them "dimension") I have one dimension linked with the value. To put the dimension and the value linked with each other, I used hashmap to do that. Example of the code:

```
ArrayList<Double> listVector1 = new ArrayList<Double>();
    listVector1.add(0.46);
    listVector1.add(0.31);
    listVector1.add(0.00);
    listVector1.add(0.00);
    listVector1.add(0.31);
    listVector1.add(0.00);
    listVector1.add(0.00);
    listVector1.add(0.31);
    listVector1.add(0.00);
    listVector1.add(0.62);
    listVector1.add(0.31);
    listVector1.add(0.00);
    listVector1.add(0.00);
    listVector1.add(0.00);
    listVector1.add(0.15);

HashMap<String, Double> testeVector1 = new HashMap<String, Double>();
    testeVector1.put("A", listVector1.get(0));
    testeVector1.put("B", listVector1.get(1));
    testeVector1.put("C", listVector1.get(2));
    testeVector1.put("D", listVector1.get(3));
    testeVector1.put("E", listVector1.get(4));
    testeVector1.put("F", listVector1.get(5));
    testeVector1.put("G", listVector1.get(6));
    testeVector1.put("H", listVector1.get(7));
    testeVector1.put("I", listVector1.get(8));
    testeVector1.put("J", listVector1.get(9));
    testeVector1.put("K", listVector1.get(1));
    testeVector1.put("L", listVector1.get(11));
    testeVector1.put("M", listVector1.get(12));
    testeVector1.put("N", listVector1.get(13));
    testeVector1.put("O", listVector1.get(14));
```

the others arrays and hashmap follow the example of this one. My problem is, I have to get the frequency of each value of each dimension which have values > 0. Example: for the dimension "A" of each one of the 5 arrays which has values > 0 I need to link in one array or, if you guys know, how can I put the frequency, the dimension and value in one hashmap, please help me to do that. Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: your question is not clear... can you elaborate

Comment: yes sure.  I need to put the frequency with each value > 0 from each array linked with the dimension and the value itself. Something like that:  testeVector1.put("A", "3" listVector1.get(0)); this number "3" is the frequency from the dimension A which appears in the five arrays and their values is > 0. In the 5 arrays I have, for the dimension "A" (or position 0 from the array) I have frequency = 3.

Comment: If you need to store both a frequency and a double number per dimension, you can just create a class for that, can be as simple as `class DimensionFrequencyValue { public final int frequency; public final double value; public DimensionFrequencyValue(int frequency, double value) { this.frequency = frequency; this.value = value; } }`, and store that as the values of your map...